# On closing browser tag delete particular data from sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using cookies, Like...

```
HttpCookie id = new HttpCookie("id");
id.Value = "2"
Response.Cookies.Add(id);
```

and i am using this cookies in a table

```
unique    cookies    productid
1          2          1
2          2          3
3          2          4
4          1          1
5          1          2
6          2          1
```

Now i want to process on browser close the data stored in the table having cookies value 2 in column(cookies) get deleted.

I mean after close of my browser tag

my table should be seen as

```
unique    cookies    productid
4          1          1
5          1          2
```

please help me

Comment: `please help me`, should that really read, `write the code for me`?

Comment: you can catch the event of browser closing using javascript and then run ajax method to clear the data from database

Comment: What's the aim of the cookies? Are you making a shopping cart of sorts?

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I want the whole solution because i don't understand how to fix it.

Comment: @Sam, Can u please explain me more with any kind of link

Comment: @Twon-ha, yes you are right i am using this in shopping cart

Comment: @MiteshJain see my answer for an example

Comment: @MiteshJain When I shop at a webstore, I regularly keep multiple tabs open for separate items or searches. If closing any one of them would empty my shopping cart, that would annoy the hell out of me. Consider doing this server-side with a session timeout if you must.

Answer (score 0):

This might work. Use Javascript/Jquery to see if browser is closing

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function () {
    $(window).unload(function () {
        //run ajax webmethod call here
    });
});
</script>
```

If the above doesn't work then do this in `body`

```
<body onbeforeunload="CloseFunction();">
```

Then create a method called `CloseFunction` and run ajax webmethod there:

```
function CloseFunction()
{
//run ajax webmethod call here
}
```

see [this link](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) on how to do ajax webmethod call

Comment: I am really sorry, I am new in asp.net.
How to use ajax web method ?
and where to make this CloseFunction(), in .cs or .aspx?
How to get my cookies value in this function?
Please Help me sir...

Comment: closeFunction() is javascript so it is in aspx file. go though the link I posted it will be clear.. you basically call a method from .cs file.

Comment: ProductBAL objbal = new ProductBAL();
objbal.Pid =Convert.ToInt32(Server.HtmlEncode(Request.Cookies["newid"].Value));
objbal.deletecookies(objbal);..............here productbal is my class and deletecookies is my storedprocedure.....now i use this coading in .cs page...but as never used javascript not knowing how to implement this code in that.......would u please help me in how to place this coading in javascript..plz